# Javascript - Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object Object] is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was hoping someone could assist me with this issue since this is not really my area.

I receive the following errors in my browser console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object Object] is not a function (index):36
(anonymous function) (index):36
Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object Object] is not a function totop.js:3
(anonymous function) totop.js:3
```

It has something to do with the slider that I have. The slider is 'Revolution Slider' for concrete5. There is somekind of conflict that I can't figure out.

It breaks the 'ToTop' function that I have, and also the mobile navigation (you see it if you minimize your browser).

Mobile Navigation Screenshot: ([link](https://www.monosnap.com/image/tJH2Jrg8TrZ0JvEnz4wux5kCa))

Live Preview: ([link](http://www.psdaddict.com/demo/flatfortuna/))

Any help is appreciated.

Best Regards,
David

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At some point in the js in the page you are doing this:

```
var tpj=jQuery;         
tpj.noConflict();
```

noConflict clears the $ (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) and the toptop script expects it to exist. Change toptop to use jQuery instead of $, or find a way to drop the noConflict call.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your code with this:

```
(function($)
{
    // your code here
    // $ now stands for jQuery
})(jQuery);
```

and be happy. No-conflict is not a solution but just another problem.